# Некорректный прием данных через COM-порт

Tags: java, arduino, serial

Есть плата Adruino Uno. С нее через Serial передаю в COM-порт данные( `if(Serial.available()) => delay(100) => Serial.write("Hello, World!")`), которые считывает Java программа. Код прилагаю. 
Проблема: программа читает из порта некорректно. Например, шлю **"Hello, World!"** - приходит **"lo, World!"**, **"orld!"**, **"orld!ld!"** и прочее. Буду благодарен за указание на стезю праведную. Аминь.

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Метод getPortNames() возвращает массив строк. Элементы массива уже отсортированы.
/*        Получение имён последовательных портов*/
        System.out.println("Port searching...");
        System.out.println("Find ports: ");
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
        for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
        //В конструктор класса передаём имя порта с которым мы будем работать
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

        //Открываем порт
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();
            //Выставляем параметры. Можно использовать и такую строку serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            //Записываем данные в порт
           serialPort.writeString("Test");
//            Лучше использовать его совместно с интерфейсом SerialPortEventListener.
            System.out.println("Getting answer from device...");
            String buffer = serialPort.readString();
            System.out.println(buffer);
            //Закрываем порт
            serialPort.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: надо шаманить с параметрами в serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE)

Comment: а не с параметрами все норм. попробуйте поствить задержку на Arduino побольше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код, написанный в функции loop() для Arduino вызывается циклически. Соответственно как только сработает условие Serial.available(), то каждые 100 мс у вас будет вызываться Serial.write("Hello, World!").